# Php exceptions not being caught

Tags: php, exception, try-catch

I am studying PHP programming and I am testing some things.

I am testing some Try Catch in Php so i made this code:

```
try{

$string s = "";
$dataraw = explode(' %\"> ', $string s);

$this->x = explode('/', $dataraw[1]);
}
catch (Exception $e)
{
    $this->x = 0;
echo 'something went wrong :)';
}
```

I designed this code to crash and launch a exception to be caught, but instead it doesnt :o
Do you know why?

Comment: Without context it's difficult to know what's going wrong.  There are some things I can guess at, that it's a PHP error you're trying to catch rather than an exception (they're not the same thing), or some class tries to throw an exception in a destructor (Throwing exceptions in destructors invariably results in an uncatchable fatal error).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code you have shown will trow a fatal error, because you are trying to access object methods on a non existing variable, but it will not throw an exception. Exceptions aren't comparable with php runtime errors. Exceptions need to be triggered explicitly by the programmer (or being triggered by libraries you are using).

A simple test may look like this:

```
try {
    throw new Exception('Something bad happened');
} catch (Exception $e) {
    die($e->getMessage());
}
```

Maybe the example is too simple to explain that topic. But explaining exceptions completely requires much more to say. You should start with reading the [PHP manual page about exceptions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php)

Comment: i undertand, but if that is the only way, why do i need try catch?

Comment: As I said, the example is too simple. Imagine that there are more function calls in the try block, and some of them might throw exceptions. Check the examples on the manual page that I've linked